# How to create another db connection with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to connect to another mysql database I am doing following

```
    $dsn = "{$dbdriver}://$vars[username]:$vars[password]@$vars[hostname]/$vars[database]";

    $db2 = $this->EE->load->database($dsn, true);
    $res = $db2->from('categories')->get()->result_array();
```

But I get error message `Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object`

That is third party script so db connection already made early. Then that script should connect to another db but 1st db connection already created

`$dsn` contains correct data. Why I get this error?
Thanks

Comment: can you output `$dsn` ? maybe there '@' or some special char in password cause problem

Comment: @safarov, I got same connection problem when I got '@' in the password. how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. The query should contains additional param `db_debug=1` so the dsn string should look like

```
$dsn = "mysql://$vars[username]:$vars[password]@$vars[hostname]/$vars[database]?db_debug=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Write parameters of 2nd database on `confid/database.php` also.

```
$db['second_db']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; 
$db['second_db']['username'] = 'foo'; 
...
```

And

```
$db2 = $this->EE->load->database('second_db', true);
```

Comment: I pull up mysql user and password on the fly in the script. So I can't set config file

Answer (score 0):

If you read the codeigniter user guide you will find the answers easily. The heading is

Connecting to Multiple Databases

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: if you see my code i do exactly as in manual and I do get connection but I can't get results because it says Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array()